# SPSite.QueryFeatures method does returns nothing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Whenever I execute the SPSite.QueryFeatures method, it returns nothing, but if I execute the SPFeature.Update on a feature that I've update using the Update-SPSolution is works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Gets a collection of features deployed in this site collection. so if your deploying your SPFeature to a site and there's no other features in site collection then you won't going to get anything, you can post all of your code to find out whats wrong, also did you tried using any of these methods,

[MSDN SPSite.QueryFeatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.queryfeatures.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If `SPFeature.QueryFeatures()` was executed in the same PowerShell instance as was `Update-SPSolution` the result will appear as if no feature upgrade is available. It is necessary to close the session and open a new instance of PowerShell (PowerGUI etc) before executing either `SPFeature.QueryFeatures()` or `SPFeature.Upgrade()`. In your case, I'm assuming that while troubleshooting why `QueryFeatures()` failed to return a result, you closed the old PS instance and opened a new PS instance and ran `Upgrade()` to see if it would work.  So the fresh PS instance is why `Upgrade()` succeeded, and the stale PS instance is why `QueryFeatures()` failed.

Comment: How is this question relevant to this question? You have already posted this answer to another question, where it do make more sense as an answer

Comment: Hi - the user executed Update-SPSolution and then exectuted QueryFeatures, expecting his updated feature to be returned, but no feature was returned.  This is precisely the behavior my answer addresses.  Thanx

Comment: Your answer is not formatted to answer this question, you should reformat it to suit this question

Comment: I reformatted the answer to better address the user's issue.  Thank you.